# redmine: time spent report including subtasks

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Is there a Redmine plugin (or maybe core functionality which I don't know how to use) which allows me to get a time entries report which includes the subtask durations?

Eg, there are tasks in hierarchy like in asciiart below:

```
#1 - new module (time spent 1h)
\
 \->#2 - prepare dev server (time spent 2h)
 |
 \->#3 - prepare images (time spent 0.5h)
```

The time_entries report should result in something like this:

```
#1 - new module         |    1:00
#2 - prepare dev server |    2:00
#3 - prepare images     |    0:30
```

If I have dozens of tasks, entries above don't say anything about them. Eg. I don't know that task #1 as whole took 3.5h, and I don't know what is #2 and #3 (because they are not linked on the report to #1)

Is there some ready code I could use which gives a hierarchical report, with total spent time for each parent entry?